# Swift 3 - UICollectionView Center Cell with Padding

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally and I would like to have one cell visible on the screen at a time.

I am programmatically setting the cell width and height in the following method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Cell

    let width = collectionView.bounds.size.width - 40
    let height = collectionView.bounds.size.height - 40

    cell.bounds.size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))

    return cell
}
```

And after struggling to figure out how to work with insets, spacing, section insets (both programmatically and in the inspectors in XCode) I can't seem to figure out what I need to set and where I need to set it.

Here is a diagram of my desired spacing:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: yourCollectionViewHeight - 40)
}
```

left 20 - add `Footer Size` and `Header Size` in storyboard with `width = 20`

spacing between cells - add `Minimum Spacing` in storyboard = 40

[image]

I could have made some mistakes and you will not get exactly your layout, but I hope you would get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width * 0.7, height: 300)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layoucollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let margin = collectionView.frame.width * 0.3
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: margin / 2, bottom: 10, right: margin / 2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return collectionView.frame.width * 0.3 / 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want single cell visible on the screen at a time then important thing is that you should **enable** **paging** for your **CollectionView**. You can do it in swift as below :

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

2. Now conform your ViewController class to **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** and implement it's method **sizeForItemAt indexPath** which returns CGSize for your collectionview cell. For Example:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {    
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
}
```